# A group of logarithmic problems - calculus question

Tags: calculus

> For $k = 2,3,4,\ldots$ we have the functions $f_k(x) = \log_k (x)$. The line $x=e$ intersects the x-axis in point $E$. We call the intersection between $f_k$ and the line $P_k$. We call the middle of the line $EP_k$, $M_k$. Proof that every $M_k$ lies on a function $f_k$.

So $EP_k$ is $\log_k(e)$. Half of that is $\dfrac{1}{2}\log_k(e) = \log_k(\sqrt{e})$. But this seems to me to be a dead end; I don't know how to show that this must lie on a function $f_k$.

Comment: For $k=1$ it is meaningless to talk of $\log_kx$.  Can you revise the question?

Comment: @David Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is stated in a slightly confusing way.  When it says "every $M_k$ lies on a function $f_k$", the $k$ in the $M_k$ does not have to be the same as the $k$ in the $f_k$.  So let's begin by rewriting it more clearly:

"Prove that every $M_k$ lies on a function $f_l$."

Since $M_k$ has coordinates $(e,\frac{1}{2}\log_ke)$, this is the same as saying $f_l(e)=\frac{1}{2}\log_ke$, that is,
$$\log_le=\frac{1}{2}\log_ke\ .$$
Now you need to solve for $l$ in terms of $k$.  Hint: do you know, or can you find out, any relationship between $\log_ab$ and $\log_ba$?

Comment: $k = \sqrt{l}$?

Comment: If this is true, how does this help our case? This only seems to prove that $P_n = M_{\sqrt{n}}$, and of course not every number has an integer square root.

Comment: @Phaptitude Now solve your equation for l in terms of k.

Comment: @user84413 lol, thanks. I totally derped.